# How can I disable realtime updates of firebase in web development?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

it is kind of trick as the real-time updating of Firebase will constantly my page, the functions built by that cannot be executed as it will update immediately. when the button and event listener is added, when i clicked on the button,  the console logged the text, it popped out for once, but it just gots updated immediately. How can i solve this? thank you so much.

```
var newbutton = document.createElement('button');
newbutton.className = 'readmorebu';
newbutton.id = Math.round(Math.random()*1000000000).toString();
newbutton.type = 'button';


control.collection('collectionName').doc('DocName').onSnapshot(function(doc){
        document.getElementById(newbutton.id).addEventListener('click',
        function(){console.log(doc.data())}
);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want realtime updates, consider [using the `get()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) to retrieve the data.

```
control.collection('collectionName').doc('DocName').get().then(function(doc){
  console.log(doc.data())
});
```